# How to remove a child component with a delete button in the child itself

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I have  an email component (email-tag.html) that consist of a label, a select and a delete button element.

The email-tag.html component is hosted in its parent email-view-tag.html. email-view-tag contains an add-email-button that adds the email-tag element to the DOM each time it is clicked.

I need help in removing an added email-tag component when its delete-button is clicked. It is the compnoent that contains the delete-button that should be removed.

The two components are shown below:

email-tag.html

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>

<polymer-element name='email-tag'>
  <template>
   <style>

   .main-flex-container
   {
     display:flex;
     flex-flow:row wrap;
     align-content:flex-start;
   }

    .col
    {
      display:flex;
      flex-flow:column;
      align-content:flex-start;
      flex-grow:1;
    }
   </style>

   <div id='email' class='main-flex-container'>
      <section id='col1' class='col'>
        <input id=emailTxt
               type='text'
               list='_emails'
               value='{{webContact.homeEmail}}'>

        <datalist id='_emails'>
            <template repeat='{{email in emails}}'>
              <option value='{{email}}'>{{email}}</option>
            </template>
        </datalist>
      </section>

      <section id='col2' class='col'>
        <button id='delete-email-btn' type='button' on-click='{{deletePhone}}'>Delete</button>
      </section>
    </div>
   </template>

   <script type="application/dart">

    import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart' show CustomTag, PolymerElement;
    import 'dart:html' show Event, Node;

    @CustomTag( 'email-tag' )
    class EmailElement extends PolymerElement
    {
      //@observable
      EmailElement.created() : super.created();
      List<String> emails = [   '', 'Home', 'Personal', 'Private', 'Work', ];

      void deletePhone( Event e, var detail, Node target)
      {
        //shadowRoot.querySelector('#new-phone' ).remove();
        //print( 'Current row deleted' );
      }
    }
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

email-view-tag.html

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>

  <link rel="import" href="email-tag.html">

  <polymer-element name='email-view-tag'>
    <template>
     <style>

     .main-flex-container
     {
       display:flex;
       flex-flow:row wrap;
       align-content:flex-start;
     }

      .col
      {
        display:flex;
        flex-flow:column;
        align-content:flex-start;
        flex-grow:1;
      }
     </style>

      <div id='email-view' class='main-flex-container'>
        <section id='row0'  >
          <button id='add-email-btn' type='button' on-click='{{addPhone}}'>Add Phone</button>
        </section >

        <section id='rows' class='col'>
       <!--    <epimss-phone-header-tag id='col1' class='col'></epimss-phone-header-tag> -->
          </section>
      </div>
     </template>

     <script type="application/dart">
      import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart' show CustomTag, PolymerElement;
      import 'dart:html' show Event, Node, Element;

      @CustomTag( 'email-view-tag' )
      class EmailViewElement extends PolymerElement
      {
        //@observable
        EmailViewElement.created() : super.created();

        void addPhone( Event e, var detail, Node target )
        {
          $[ 'rows' ].children.add( new Element.tag( 'email-tag' ) );
        }

        @override
        void attached() {
          super.attached();

          $[ 'add-email-btn' ].click();
        }
      }
    </script>
  </polymer-element>
```

The application does execute normally and clicking the add button does add the email component. The delete button does not work - it is here I am asking for help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The child component, `<email-tag>` should not be in the business of deleting itself. Instead, it should delegate that responsibility to the the parent component, `email-view-tag`, by dispatching a custom event.

Here is the code for dispatching a custom event from `deletePhone`:

```dart
void deletePhone( Event e, var detail, Node target){
  dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('notneeded'));
}
```

Then, in the parent, `<custom-view>`, change your code for adding `<email-tag>`s like so:

```dart
void addPhone( Event e, var detail, Node target ) {
  $['rows'].children.add( new Element.tag('email-tag'));
  $['rows'].on["notneeded"].listen((Event e) {
    (e.target as Element).remove();
  });
}
```

Also, I would change the name of `deletePhone`, since the method no longer deletes the record but merely informs the parent that it is not needed. Call it 'notNeeded' or something similar.

Comment: Sure. If you find the answer works for you, would you mind accepting it?

Comment: Sure Tuli, the answer is exactly what I wanted. Thanks again.

Comment: Can you please accept the answer? You can do so by clicking on the checkmark towards the top left of the question,  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
@ShailenTuli is right about encapsulation should not be broken.

But also JS Polymer elements access the parent in their layout elements because it's still convenient in some scenarios.

This works now in PolymerDart too.

```dart
(this.parentNode as ShadowRoot).host
```

**ORIGINAL**

You can fire an event and make the email-view-tag listen to this tag and the event handler can remove the event target from it's childs.

- I had a similar question a while ago: 
  [How to access parent model from polymer component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20340539/how-to-access-parent-model-from-polymer-component/20342142#20342142)
- This was actually the question I wanted refer to
  [How can I access the host of a custom element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19977163/how-can-i-access-the-host-of-a-custom-element)
  but the first one may be of some use too.
- [PolymerJS FAQ - When is the best time to access an element’s parent node?](http://www.polymer-project.org/resources/faq.html#parentnode)
  `attached()` <del>currently still named `enteredView()` in Dart, but will be renamed probably soon.</del>

Comment: Thanks ZOechi. I am not very familiar with Dart events. Could you please add some code to demonstrate this for my components. I will have to dig into these events all the same. Thanks