# Accessing state from other web components in Dart

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

Let's say that you have one web component stored inside of another in Dart. Is there any way to access state from other components?

Let's say that I have a Polymer element called `x-notebook-element` and one called `x-note-element` embedded inside of it (via an iterator):

```html
<polymer-element name="x-notebook-element">
  <template>
    <ul>
      <template repeat="{{note in notes}}">
        <li is="x-note-element" note="{{note}}"></li>
      </template>
    </ul>
  </template>

  <script type="application/dart" src="notebook.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

The difficulty is that I want to be able to click on a `Delete` button *within an `x-note-element`* that removes the `x-note-element` from the DOM *and* removes the `note` associated with it from the `notes` list.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove a child component with a delete button in the child itself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20406328/how-to-remove-a-child-component-with-a-delete-button-in-the-child-itself)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fire a `CustomEvent` in your `x-note-element` :

```dart
dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('my-delete-event', detail: note.id));
```

And listen to those events :

```html
<li is="x-note-element" note="{{note}}" on-my-delete-event="{{delete}}"></li>
```

Then in the dart part of `x-notebook-element` :

```dart
delete(CustomEvent e, var detail, Element target) {
  final deletedId = e.detail;
  // update notes
}
```