# Is it possible to render a List<Element> in Polymer.dart?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, polymer

Given a `List<Element> elements`, is it possible to render the elements in the template, like this?

```
<template repeat="{{element in elements}}">
    {{element.SOMETHING}}
</template>
```

I'd want it to observe the list too, so that it would add and remove elements as the list changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

A ready-to-use element for Dart Polymer 1.0 is [bwu-bind-html](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/bwu_bind_html)

---

`{{}}` can't include HTML.

You can use something like the `<safe-html>` tag (see answer to [HTML Tags Within Internationalized Strings In Polymer.dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20868296))

```dart
<template repeat="{{element in elements}}">
    <safe-html model="{{element.SOMETHING}}"></safe-html>
</template>
```

but I guess you have to change the `<self-html>` implementation so that it replaces itself with the content of `model` instead of adding `model` to it's content, because `ul`/`ol` can't contain `<self-html>`

Comment: You may take a look at my answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20406328 if you need access to the parent to make the element replace itself.