# Is there a way to swap one polymer component for another?

Tags: polymer

I'm stuck a bit conceptually. I've created a builder component for managing the input of data via an AJAX post. On return, I'll have a JSON object that I can render to the client. Optimally, I'd like to instantiate a new render component, pass the JSON object to it, and then destroy the builder component (door number two is a simple page reload, but that seems like a very 1990s hammer for a 21st century nail).

Representative (simplified) builder component:

```
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/core-ajax/core-ajax.html">

<polymer-element name="post-builder" attributes="accesstoken">
    <template>
        <core-ajax id="poster" url="api_call" handleAs="json"></core-ajax>
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" placeholder="Enter text here." value="{{ body }}"></textarea>
        <div class="postControls">
            <div class="sendLink">
                <a href="javascript:null;" on-click="[[ postAndReplaceTile ]]">Post</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>
    <script>
        created: function(){
            this.body = '';
        },
        ready: function(){

        },
        postAndReplaceTile: function(){
            data = {body : this.body, publish : true};

            var ajax = this.$.poster;
            ajax.removeEventListener('core-response');

            ajax.method = 'POST';
            ajax.contentType = 'application/json';
            ajax.params = { access_token: this.accesstoken };
            ajax.body = JSON.stringify(data);
            ajax.addEventListener('core-response', function(){
                if(this.response.hasOwnProperty('post')){
                    if(this.response.post.hasOwnProperty('id')){

                        // valid JSON object of the new post

                    }
                }
            }); 
            ajax.go();


        }
    });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

At the stage of the valid JSON object, I'm looking for a moral equivalent of jQuery's replaceWith()...recognizing that the JSON object is in the component that's being replaced so I need to sequence these events carefully. Is there a way to cleanly reach up to the parent DOM and do these types of transformations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `parentNode.host` (see [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/polymer-dev/otfo-7t5zcE)) to access the container element and use `DOM` methods to replace the element but that's somehow an anti-pattern and breaks encapsulation (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19977163/how-can-i-access-the-host-of-a-custom-element) and [here](http://japhr.blogspot.co.at/2014/02/child-polymers-should-not-access-parent.html)).

It's proably better to use `events` and let the container element take care of swaping the elements.

Comment: That's really helpful, thanks. I think I've moved past the concept and now working towards building components that have create, edit and display views all self-contained. Just a continuous shift of thinking away from jQuery...